# Angular 2 and Bootstrap 4 open Dialog

Tags: angular, dialog, modal-dialog

i have a question. How can i open a simple component as dialog? I would like to open a dialog after i click on a button. I use Angular 2.4 and Bootstrap 4 alpha 6.

I found this: https://github.com/shlomiassaf/angular2-modal but there will no component used to dispay it.

Comment: why do you need a component as dialog?

Comment: on the main page you can click on an add button and then the dialog open where you can create a product. The product component give the information to the server over http

Comment: what are you doing is it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the `NgbModal` service from https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal you can very easily open dialogs (modals) for which content comes from a component. Here is how:

```
modalService.open(YourComponentToShowAsDialog);
```

Yes, this is it :-) Just remember to add `YourComponentToShowAsDialog` to the `entryComponents` section of your module.

Finally, here is a plunker demonstrating how it can work in practice: http://plnkr.co/edit/XzUbRiBfqSKmmOYhZtPJ?p=preview